# Forcing pyspark join to occur sooner

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lazy-evaluation

PROBLEM: I have two tables that are vastly different in size. I want to join on some id by doing a left-outer join.  Unfortunately, for some reason even after caching my actions after the join are being executed on all records even though I only want the ones from the left table.  See below:

MY QUESTIONS:
 1. How can I set this up so only the records that match the left table get processed through the costly wrangling steps?

LARGE_TABLE => ~900M records

SMALL_TABLE => 500K records

CODE:

```
combined = SMALL_TABLE.join(LARGE_TABLE SMALL_TABLE.id==LARGE_TABLE.id, 'left-outer')
print(combined.count())
...
...
# EXPENSIVE STUFF!
w = Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("date_time"))
data = data.withColumn('diff_id_flag', when(lag('id').over(w) != col('id'), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)))
```

Unfortunately, my execution plan shows the expensive transformation operation above is being done on ~900M records.  I find this odd since I ran df.count() to force the join to execute eagerly rather than lazily.

Any Ideas?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
 - note that the expensive transformation in my code flow occurs after the join (at least that is how I interpret it) but my DAG shows the expensive transformation occurring as a part of the join.  This is exactly what I want to avoid as the transformation is expensive.  I want the join to execute and THEN the result of that join to be run through the expensive transformation.
 - Assume the smaller table CANNOT fit into memory.

Comment: sorry. was just putting something in there to show I was doing some expensive transformation. statement added is more illustrative.

Comment: You might want to try persisting the dataframe after the join. Then run `df.count()` followed by your expensive wrangling operation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to [broadcast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@broadcast[T](df:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) the tiny dataframe. Caching is good for multiple actions, which doesnt seem to be applicable ro your particular use case.

Comment: suppose my small dataframe is now a half a million records though?  obviously still don't want to do complex wrangling on all of the 900M large table records.

Comment: @DonaldVetal it really depends on the actual size of the smaller dataframe. (whether this can fit in memory) I am not really sure what you mean by wrangling, but in a join you have to iterate through every row. Unless your transformation before join is too expensive, in which case you should probably join first then transform.

Comment: added additional information at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

- `df.count` has no effect on the execution plan at all. It is just expensive operation executed without any good reason.
- Window function application in this requires the same logic as `join`. Because you join by `id` and `partitionBy` `id`both stages will require the same hash partitioning and full data scan for both sides. There is no acceptable reason to separate these two.

  In practice `join` logic should be applied before window, serving as a filter for the the downstream transformations in the same stage.